# The area of $ABCD$ is $84$. The diagonals meet at $P$, and $|AP|=5$, $|BP|=3$, $|CP|=7$, $|DP|=2$. Find the areas of the four sub-triangles.

Tags: geometry

> The area of quadrilateral $ABCD$ is $84$. The diagonals intersect at point $P$. If
>   $$|AP|= 5,\quad|BP|= 3,\quad|CP|= 7,\quad|DP|= 2, $$
>   calculate the area of the four triangles in quadrilateral $ABCD$.

Comment: please include your attempt if possible when you ask a question on this site.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** draw the perpendicular from $A$ onto the $BD$ diagonal. What's the ratio of the areas for triangles $ABP$ and $APD$? Repeat the procedure and write all areas in term of the area of $ABP$. Sum them together and you find the area of $ABCD$.